# if statement on uiimageview isn't working

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview, if-statement

I declared an ib outlet as an uiimageview and attempted this code:

```
    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
    if (section > 1){
        mySpeech.hidden = YES;
    }
}
```

mySpeech is the uiimageview...

But it isn't working! Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put that `return` statement last, because nothing after it will ever be executed.

Comment: Hmm, this didnt work: - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
 id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    if (section > 1){
  mySpeech.hidden = YES;
 } 
 return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
}

Comment: You're misusing this method. It is *not* designed to make adjustments to your views or content, it *just* should remember the number of rows. Setting something hidden should go in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:. Also, don't forget to set hidden = NO in the other cases. But again, this method is not the right place for this.